# 90-Day Non Engaged Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to create a query based on people who have *not* opened an email in the past 90 days.

The Error Being Received:

> A problem occurred creating your query definition. Please contact
>   Customer Service for additional information. Error saving the Query
>   field.Field 'Subscriber ID' is a required for the Target Data
>   Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query text.

The Query:

```
SELECT distinct SubscriberID     
FROM _Sent s 
WHERE EventDate > dateadd(day,-90,getdate()) 
AND SubscriberID NOT IN (
  SELECT SubscriberID
  FROM _Open 
  WHERE EventDate >  dateadd(day,-90,getdate())
)
AND s.listid = 170095
```

** I have also tried using SELECT distinct SubscriberKey**

Does anyone know where I may be going wrong? 
Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the SubscriberID as a required field in your target Data Extension or exclude null SubscriberIDs in the where clause of your query.

```
SELECT distinct s.SubscriberID     
FROM _Sent s 
WHERE s.EventDate > dateadd(day,-90,getdate()) 
AND s.SubscriberID NOT IN (
  SELECT o.SubscriberID
  FROM _Open o
  WHERE o.EventDate >  dateadd(day,-90,getdate())
)
AND s.listid = 170095
AND s.SubscriberID is not null
```